# NetBeans Cant find rt.jar when building

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I have a simple Java project in NetBeans7.2, and when I try to Clean/Build it fails:

```
Building jar: D:\MEUS PROJETOS\_Workspace\JavaWorkspace\Mina\dist\Mina.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "D:\MEUS PROJETOS\_Workspace\JavaWorkspace\Mina\dist\Mina.jar"
Realizando o ofuscamento do código
Obfuscating dist/Mina.jar...
Created dir: D:\MEUS PROJETOS\_Workspace\JavaWorkspace\Mina\build\obfuscated
ProGuard, version 4.8
Reading program jar [D:\MEUS PROJETOS\_Workspace\JavaWorkspace\Mina\dist\Mina.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jna.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Library\Java\Home\lib\rt.jar]
D:\MEUS PROJETOS\_Workspace\JavaWorkspace\Mina\build.xml:28: Can't read [C:\Library\Java\Home\lib\rt.jar] (No such file or directory)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

It's odd because I **don't** have that [C:\Library\Java\Home\lib\rt.jar] called in my project's library (there is no "C:\Library" in my computer at all)!

Also, why "rt.jar" is called again, if it's already called from "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar"?

I have absolutely no idea where this came from, nor where I can change it (because it is not in my project's library list).

Thanks in advance! Forgive my bad english...

EDITED:
I just figured out that this issue doesn't happen when the application is compiled (build), but when NetBeans' ProGuard4.8 plugin try to Obfuscate!

Comment: Can you see anything about that path in `build.xml` or `project.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that by "simple Java project" you mean the "Java application" project from "Java" category in NetBeans "New Project..." action from "File" menu.

Netbeans default [build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) is [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html). Ant is the program that compiles, packs and runs the source code from your project.

If you can't find the string "C:\Library\Java\Home\lib\rt.jar" *anywhere* in the project Properties window, the next place to look for are the properties files inside the nb-folder in project root (change from "Projects" to "Files" view) or the build{-impl}.xml files.

When you click on the "Clean and Build" action from the right click on the project icon in the "Projects" view ant reads the build.xml file (which imports the build-impl.xml file), finds the clean and jar [targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html), calculates all the dependent targets and [properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) needed to successfully run the aforementioned targets and finnally runs the calculated sequence of targets.

But, if it is a project made through the NetBeans "New project" action, the build.xml and nb-project are automatically generated, and changing the project properties from GUI effectivley changes the parts of build-impl.xml and some other files. In case you hadn't edited the automatically generated files, that is not the place to look for.

The next thing is to consider if it is Netbeans cache issue, see [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir) for it's location, enter that directory and delete its contents (I can't guarantee it will help though).

Interesting thing is that rt.jar is usually in JRE_HOME/lib directory where JRE_HOME is full path to some [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7u9-downloads-1859586.html) installation, so that might lead to conslusion that you have an JRE_HOME [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) set to this (nonexistent) location.

It's all just guesses but something of this should help you. Please feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I tried your ideas (I learned a lot of new stuff...), but didn't work.
**BUT:** Reading again the output log I saw an important detail: the problem is not happening when the application is compiled, but when the ProGuard4.8 plugin try to Obfuscate it!!! I will edit my question.

Comment: np, look for ProGuard plugin conifguration options(both gui and text), it's probably requesting the rt.jar at nonexistent location.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!!! Thank you! I found that in the build.xml file, line 15, the JAVA_HOME path was `<property name="java.home.path" value="/Library/Java/Home/"/>` and I changed to `<property name="java.home.path" value="/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/jre/"/>` and worked like magic! I got some help here also: [link](http://www.javawebonline.com/java-se-programming/beginners/java_home-jre_home-environment-variables/) [link](http://netbeans.dzone.com/tips/obfuscating-netbeans-java-appl)