# Can't resolve jdk.internal package

Tags: java, netbeans

NetBeans seems to be not able to resolve `jdk.internal.*` classes, but other internal API (i.e. `com.sun.*`) has no problem resolving.

```
Compile : "jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader does not exist" <br>
(This package exists in rt.jar)
```

Is this NetBeans bug?

```
NetBeans: 8.0 (Build 201403101706)<br>
Java: 1.8.0_20-ea; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.20-b20<br>
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetBeans Cant find rt.jar when building](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016037/netbeans-cant-find-rt-jar-when-building)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is javac's restriction. By default, javac does not read classes from rt.jar. It reads from a symbol file, which only contains standard API and some internal API (e.g. com.sun.*, com.oracle.* and sun.*).

To disable this mechanism, I can use javac `-XDignore.symbol.file=true` option.

For Maven, edit POM file like the following.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, I can build project without error, but Error notification remains on NetBeans editor UI. To remove these error, I append `-J-DCachingArchiveProvider.disableCtSym` option in NETBEANS_HOME/etc/netbeans.conf file.

```
netbeans_default_options="... -J-DCachingArchiveProvider.disableCtSym=true"
```

Finally, I removed all error from NetBeans environment.

Comment: Per @karmakaze answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac <fork>true</fork> must be included in <configuration> element. That was the case for me too, my Maven is 3.3